# jquery msg plugin overlay another jquery plugin looped using php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have data to display in table and i used loop statement to echo it on the table. and when it click an url a msgbox plugin show and ask if you want to delete that data.  but the problem is, another msgbox will overlay the other one and if i try to click the 2 row url it doesnt show any msgbox, only in the 1st row show, and all because of that looping statement i did. here is my code:

```
<table id="datatables_event" class="display">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Article Title</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
                    {
                ?>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[0]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[8]?></td>
                    <td>
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td><a href="#" id="delete"><img src="images/Delete_Icon.png"alt="Delete" style="width:25px; height:25px" id="imgdel"/></a></td><td></td>
                    <td><a href="event.php?ueventid=<?php echo $row[5]; ?>"><img src="images/Update.png"alt="Update" style="width:25px; height:25px"/></a></td>
                    </tr> 
</table>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    }//end of while
                    exit;
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

this is my js:

```
$( function(){
                            $( '#imgdel' ).bind( 'click', function(){
                                  $.msg({
                                    method: 'insertAfter',
                                    target: '#delete',
                                      autoUnblock : false,
                                      clickUnblock : true,
                                      content: '<p>Delete this user?</p>' +
                                       '<p class="btn-wrap">' +
                                         '<span id="yes">Yes</span>' +
                                         '<span id="no">no</span>' +
                                       '</p>',
                        });
                        });
                        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are causing an error by assigning the same `id` to multiple elements. An `id` can only be used once. Hence id: identifier. So you should give the anchors a class and trigger your JS from that. Also, give the elements a unique id, by adding your database id to the element id.

Comment: and how should i do that? any suggestions?

Comment: In your row there must be an id field. So you can do `id="imgdel_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"`

Comment: and how should i assign that in javascript? like this? $( '#imgdel_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>' ).bind( 'click', function(){. . . .

Comment: No, your js function binds on the class. Like `$( '.imgdel' ).bind( 'click', function(){....` (notice the point instead of the hash). Now, inside this function, the element you clicked on is available as `$(this)`. You can then use this in your callback.

Comment: I mean in your function, instead of callback

Comment: i dont know where should i put this id="imgdel_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>", in acnhor tag or in imgage? and also in js. could you give me example?

Comment: Please, read my answer again, do some study about the difference between `class` and `id` (and why an id has to be unique). If you are still in doubt after that, give me another call.

Comment: Ok, that's good. Now look in your code and you will see that you will have a lot of elements with the same id. `<a href="#" id="delete">` and `id="imgdel"` in the `img` tag. That is because these are inside the `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))` loop. So, in order to make these id's unique you will have to do something like `id="imgdel_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"`. After you have done that, you cannot trigger your JS onclick event on an id (since they are unique), thus instead trigger them on a class. Then use the `$(this)` statement in your JS function. Still need more help? Let me know